# how to make a compressed js files with all pages in nuxt js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am running a nuxt js application built with adonuxt. The app works just fine. But I see all pages are loading one by one and make the site a bit slow for the initial load. The site's interactivity doesn't work until all js chunk is not loaded.

So how can I make a one js file with all the pages. 
Also I don't want to load the admin pages in the website. How can I separate this.

My nuxt config is like this..

```
    'use strict'

    const resolve = require('path').resolve


    module.exports = {
    /*
    ** Headers of the page
    */
    env: {
        baseUrl: 'https://savingfamilybazar.com/'
    },

    build: {
        vendor:[ 'vue-product-zoomer'] 
    },
    modules: [
        '@nuxtjs/axios',

    ],
    axios: {

    },
    plugins: [
        '~plugins/vuetify',
        '~plugins/element',
        {src: '~plugins/zoom', ssr: false}
    ],

    head: {
        title: 'my site',
        meta: [
        {
            charset: 'utf-8'
        },
        {
            name: 'viewport',
            content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'
        },
        {
            hid: 'description',
            name: 'description',
            content: 'site.....'
        },

        ],
        link: [
        {
            rel: 'icon',
            type: 'image/x-icon',
            href: '/favicon.ico',
        },
        ],
        script: [
            { src: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/6.26.0/polyfill.min.js' },
            { src: 'https://unpkg.com/@adonisjs/websocket-client' },
        ],
    },
    /*
    ** Global CSS
    */
    css: [

        //'~assets/css/main.css',


    ],
    /*
    ** Customize the progress-bar color
    */
    loading: { color: '#ffd451',height:'3px' },
    /*
    ** Point to resources
    */
    srcDir: resolve(__dirname, '..', 'resources')
    }
```

Currently it loads like this

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, code splitting the pages should make your page faster. Because each route loads only the files it needs.

So if you have all the pages in one bundle it will be even slower. Because you need to load everything on the initial load.

You should check if your hoster supports HTTP2. This should boost the speed.

However, if you want to disable the automatic code-splitting in routes you have to edit the config.

```
build: {
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'async',
      }
    },
    splitChunks: {
      pages: false,
      vendor: false,
      commons: false,
      runtime: false,
      layouts: false
    },
}
```

https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build#splitchunks

https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/pull/3060